# Unable to position links on responsive CSS design?

Tags: wordpress, css

I have a responsive website that I am unable to position without effecting the existing navigation...

I have the following code in a wordpress site...

http://alanbrandt.com

Client-Side HTML

```
<!-- wrapper -->
<div class="wrapper">
    <!--[if lt IE 8]>
        <p class="chromeframe">Your browser is <em>ancient!</em>  <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">Upgrade to a different browser</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">install Google Chrome Frame</a> to experience this site.</p>
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- header -->
    <header id="header-main">
        <!-- logo --> <a id="rel-top"></a>

        <div id="logo"> <a href="http://alanbrandt.com">
                            <!-- svg logo - toddmotto.com/mastering-svg-use-for-a-retina-web-fallbacks-with-png-script -->
                            <h1 id="logo"><img src="http://alanbrandt.com/wp-content/themes/alanbrandt/images/logo.svg" alt="Alan Brandt Photography"></h1>
                        </a>

        </div>
        <!-- /logo -->
        <!-- nav -->
        <nav id="nav-main" role="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li id="menu-item-161" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-161"><a class="expandStories top" href="http://alanbrandt.com/stories">Stories</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-18" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-18"><a href="http://alanbrandt.com/about-me/">About me</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-40" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-40"><a href="http://alanbrandt.com/portfolio/">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-41" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-41"><a href="http://alanbrandt.com/prices/">Prices</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-16" class="ContactMenu menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-16"><a href="http://alanbrandt.com/contact/">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li class='last'>
                    <form role='search' method='get' id='searchform' action='http://alanbrandt.com' class=''>
                        <fieldset>
                            <input type='text' value='' name='s' id='s' placeholder='Search' />
                            <input type='submit' id='searchsubmit' value='Search' />
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class='cf'></div>
            <div id="language"> <a href="http://alanbrandt.dk">Dansk</a> | <a href="http://alanbrandt.com">English</a>

            </div>
        </nav>
```

If I use the below CSS to align the Dansk|English links users are no longer able to click on the navigation links???

CSS

```
.language {
  position:relative;
  left:340px;
  top:-27px;
}
```

Can someone expain how this should be done. I am not a developer so please provide me details... :)

Thanks in advance... :)

Comment: How about showing your actual HTML, not your PHP server code.

Comment: Do you mean you need more than what is shown in the header.php section? The HTML is there `<div class="language">` Otherwise there is also a link to the site.

Comment: Client-side problems should show client-side code. Your PHP is irrelevant to answering this question.

Comment: The PHP generates the client-side code, so I am guessing the issue is there, plus there is also a link to the site.

Comment: I have added the client-side code to the question hope this helps and thank you for your input so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user cannot click the navigation links because you haven't set the language div's width (100% by default) and you're using negative values which moves the language div on top of the navigation block.

My solution would be the following:

CSS:

```
  .wrapper {
   margin: 0 auto;      /* Center your contents */
   max-width: 780px;    /* Set the maximum width for your wrapper! */ 
   width: 100%;
   }

  #language {
   position: relative;
   top: -27px;
   float: right;        /* You're floating the div to the right */
   width: 100px;        /* Now you've set the width on the language div */
   }
```

This is just one way of solving the problem. Let me know if you need further help. 
 [image: Here's how it looks like]

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks for the input... It's close to what I want but now it is on right on the edge of the browser. Ideally it should align virtically with the picture frame. Is there also a way to get the links to inherit the same style as the navigation ordered list?

Comment: Well yeah, because you haven't set the width for your wrapper! Have another look at the code I provided.

Comment: I did... It didn't work... I have found another solution, but you put me on the right track with the float thanks... :)

Comment: Maybe not... my solution now makes the top `nav` move off center if you see what I mean... I thought if I included it in the Navigation it might work, but I cannot get the navigation to stay still while I align the "Dansk | English" links???

Comment: I've tested my code in every browser and it's working fine. So you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Try #header-main instead of .wrapper then.

Comment: Thank you... Sorry I was editing #wrapper and not .wrapper... I really appreciate your help! :)